# How to increase and change the styles and width and height in fileupload control button using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I am using FileUpload control in my webpage it is working but my requirement is **increase the button size in upload control** but cann't change the textbox size how it possible pls help me any one if u know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't see the width effect in firefox, for that you have to add **size="50"** to make effect in firefox.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Width="500px" size="50" />
```

Let me know your result.

Comment: Yes you are correct @Arun. For every browser `width` attribute work, I mean as for height, `size` is only working in firefox

Answer (score 0):

For upload files use "plupload" http://www.plupload.com/
In this case you will be able to set any styles for upload button.

In case if you don't use it then you will not be able to change style, because all browsers displays upload area in different styles.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried as below, It is working.

```
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" Height="25.5" />
```